# Trying to get the c# equivalent of a c++ class

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

i'm trying to get the C# equivalent of a C++ class, i've very very basic knowledge in C++ so idk if that's really possible or not. I've try something but i'm stuck. So if you can help me to "parse" this c++ class to c# and explain me how you do it or give some link who could help me. (Or give me a tips for using this c++ class into my c# project (idk if it's possible because of the managed/unmanaged code etc..)

C++ class:

```
class GameString
{
public:
    GameString (GameString const&) = delete;
    GameString& operator=(GameString const&) = delete;

    GameString (const std::string &str)
        : _buf (8)
    {
        append (str);
        setHeader (1, length ());
    }

    GameString& operator+=(const std::string &str)
    {
        append (str);
        setHeader (1, length ());

        return *this;
    }

    std::size_t length ()
    {
        return _buf.size () - 8;
    }
    char *str ()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>(_buf.data () + 8);
    }

private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> _buf;

    void append (const std::string &str)
    {
        for (auto &c : str)
        {
            _buf.push_back (c);
        }
    }

    void setHeader (std::size_t ref, std::size_t len)
    {
        memcpy (&_buf[0], &ref, 4);
        memcpy (&_buf[4], &len, 4);
    }
};
```

C# class:

```
class GameString
{
    private List<char> _buf = new List<char>(8);

    public GameString(string str)
    {
        Append(str);
        SetHeader(1, Length());
    }

    private void Append(string str)
    {
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            _buf.Add(c);
        }
    }

    public int Length()
    {
        return _buf.Count - 8;
    }

    public string Str()
    {
        // return new String(_buf.ToArray());
    }

    private void SetHeader(int rf, int length)
    {
        // memcpy(&_buf[0], &ref, 4);
        // memcpy(&_buf[4], &len, 4);
    }
}
```

And thanks for your help

Comment: It might help if you could detail the behavior you need from the c# class.

Comment: Seems like your essentially asking how `Str()` should be implemented. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm looking for, i'm trying to get the same result from both str() method and how i can make the SetHeader() method in C# because it probably change the value and i can't ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GameString
{
    private MemoryStream buf;

    public GameString(string str)
    {
        buf = new MemoryStream();

        // 8 empty bytes at the beginning
        buf.SetLength(8);
        buf.Position = 8;

        Append(str);
    }

    // Different from C++ implementation. This one is public
    // and updates the SetHeader
    public void Append(string str)
    {
        byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        buf.Write(utf8, 0, utf8.Length);
        SetHeader(1, Length);
    }

    public static GameString operator +(GameString gs, string str)
    {
        gs.Append(str);
        return gs;
    }

    // This one is a property instead of being a method
    public int Length { get => (int)buf.Length - 8; }

    // The char *str ()
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf.GetBuffer(), 8, (int)buf.Length - 8);
    }

    // This one was missing in the C++ implementation. Returns the internal buffer.
    // trimmed to the correct length. Note that it creates a copy!
    public byte[] ToByteArray()
    {
        return buf.ToArray();
    }

    private void SetHeader(int @ref, int len)
    {
        // This could be optimized. Sadly the GetBytes create new
        // arrays as the return value, instead of writing to a 
        // preexisting array.
        byte[] temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(@ref);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, buf.GetBuffer(), 0, temp.Length);

        temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(len);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, buf.GetBuffer(), 4, temp.Length);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var gs = new GameString("Foo");
gs.Append("Bar");
gs.Append("Baz");
gs += "Hello";
gs += "World";
string str = gs.ToString();
byte[] bytes = gs.ToByteArray();
```

I've made some changes to the C++ code, commented inside the C# code.

I'm using `MemoryStream` instead of a `List<>` or a `StringBuilder`. `char` in C# is 2 bytes, while in C it is 1 byte, so in C# you should use `byte`, not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the header is seemingly a fixed value of 1 and the length, unless i'm missing something

You could easily just use [`string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`string.Length();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// instantiate
string gameString = "sadasd";

// get length
var len = gameString.Length();

// append
gameString += "sdfsfsdfdsf";

// get length again
var newLen = gameString.Length();
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not that simple. I'm trying to send packet to a game server but the string in the packet can't be a simple string and that's why this class is create, for "transform" a classic string to correct packet string. ex: the str() method of GameString gamestr("mypacket") return: mypacketÍÍýý and when i send this packet to the server it work but when i'm sending just "mypacket" he doesn't work. Hope you understand, my english is very bad :/

Comment: So what does the server want, just standard ascii bytes?